# Calculate SQL Column based upon "looping" through another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add a column to my query of Lab Specimens that will loop through all possible rows of another table and then calculate a status of INHOUSE, EXTERNAL or MULTISITE.
This needs to be done look at a different table that lists multiple rows against each row from the first table.

- If ALL instances of TestSite in the second table are 'XX'. then column should say INHOUSE
- If NO instances of TestSite in the second table are 'XX'. then column should say EXTERNAL
- If SOME instances of TestSite in the second table are 'XX'. then column should say MULTISITE

Being relatively new at SQL coding, can anyone advise how I can calculate the relevant value from the 2nd table? Would it be some sort of loop through the 2nd table?

I've tried doing table joins and CASE statements, but I am just getting multiple rows per specimen, where I am looking to get 1 single row per specimen.

```
SELECT 
       SpecimenID
  FROM [LabSpecimens] LS  --this is the base table

SELECT 
      ,[SpecimenID]
      ,[TestSite]
  FROM [LabSpecimenTests]  --this is the table I want to calculate the extra column from
```

The 2 table might look like this:

```
SpecimenID
----------
1
2
3
4


SpecimenID   TestSite
----------   --------
1            XX
2            YY
2            ZZ
3            YY
3            YY
3            XX
4            YY
4            ZZ
4            XX
```

Expected result should look like:

```
SpecimenID    Status
----------    ---------
1             INHOUSE
2             EXTERNAL
3             INHOUSE
4             MULTISITE
```

Any ideas/assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your SpecimenID 3 has three 'YY's and marked as INHOUSE but the rule says `If ALL instances of TestSite in the second table are 'XX'. then column should say INHOUSE` Can you clarify

Comment: apologies!!! Fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't think you need to `JOIN` the two tables.

Second, assuming that the values are actually arbitrary, I don't want to depend on the ordering of the strings.  So, I would suggest:

```
SELECT T2.SpecimenID, 
       (CASE WHEN MAX(TestSite) = MIN(T2.TestSite) AND MIN(T2.TestSite)  = 'XX'
             THEN 'INHOUSE'   -- All XX
             WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN T2.TestSite = 'XX' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
             THEN 'MULTISITE' -- Some XX
             ELSE 'EXTERNAL'
        END)
FROM Tab2 T2
GROUP BY T2.SpecimenID;
```

Or, without aggregation, you can do:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when not exists (select 1  -- no record that is not an XX
                              from table2 t2
                              where t2.specimenid = t1.specimenid and
                                    t2.testsite <> 'XX'
                             )
             then 'INHOUSE'
             when exists (select 1       -- Some record that is an XX
                          from table2 t2
                          where t2.specimenid = t1.specimenid and
                                t2.testsite = 'XX'
                         )
             then 'MULTISITE'
             ELSE 'EXTERNAL'
       END)
from table1 t1;
```

Because this avoids the aggregation it is likely to be faster with an index on `tables(specimenid, testsite)`.

Comment: I've tried the non-aggregation option above, but I don't seem to get the right results. Every specimen is shown as MULTISITE, even though I've checked rows and there are definitely a mix of at least INHOUSE and MULTISITE.

Comment: Here is my code block I used:

,(case when not exists (select 1
                              from table2 t2
                              where t2.SpecimenID = t2.SpecimenID and
                                    t2.TestSite <> 'XX'
                             )
             then 'INHOUSE'
             when exists (select 1
                          from table2 t2
                          where t2.SpecimenID = t2.SpecimenID and
                                t2.TestSite = 'XX'
                         )
             then 'MULTISITE'
             ELSE 'EXTERNAL'
       END

Comment: @childofsai . . . `t2.SpecimenID = t2.SpecimenID` is not the correct correlation condition.

Comment: Power of the Post! I also just spotted that, and now it's all working perfectly.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a conditional aggreagtion and analize the result using case

```
select SpecimenID, case when t.count = t.XX then  'INHOUSE'
                        when t.XX = 0 then 'EXTERNAL' 
                        ELSE 'MULTISITE' 
                  end  
from (
    select SpecimenID
        , count(*) count 
        , sum( case when testSite = 'XX' then 1 else 0 end ) XX
    from  table2  
    group by SpecimenID
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this below script. According to your logic, 3 should be tagged with 'EXTERNAL' but you mentioned 'INHOUSE'

```
SELECT T1.SpecimenID, 
CASE 
    WHEN MAX(TestSite) = 'XX' AND MIN(TestSite)  = 'XX'  THEN 'INHOUSE'
    WHEN MIN(TestSite) = 'XX' AND MAX(TestSite)  <> 'XX' THEN 'MULTISITE'
    ELSE 'EXTERNAL'
END
FROM Tab1 T1
INNER JOIN Tab2 T2 ON T1.SpecimenID = T2.SpecimenID
GROUP BY T1.SpecimenID
```

The output will be as below-

```
SpecimenID Status
1          INHOUSE
2          EXTERNAL
3          EXTERNAL
4          MULTISITE
```

Check fiddle output [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cfaf4237763627c5e29b9dff08dda906)